# how to Upload a txt or csv file to windows form c#

Tags: c#, file-upload

I want to upload a txt or csv file through windows form in c# and want to import the data to database ( sql server). how can i do that? i am facing 2 problems:-

1. i have not got any tools for file uploading, there is only image uploading tool available.
2. if somehow i have manage to do file uploading, how can i then import data from txt file to sql server database?

it will be good and helpfull to me if anyone can help by c# code solutions?

Comment: you should provide a little bit more content, like: what system are you on? Desktop, Website,..? what did you try so far? etc.. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Loading `csv` into RDBMS is * *typical import task*, there're number of means to perform it. Do not reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below :

```
private void buttonGetFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    dialog.Filter = "Text files | *.txt"; // file types, that will be allowed to upload
    dialog.Multiselect = false; // allow/deny user to upload more than one file at a time
    if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) // if user clicked OK
    {
        String path = dialog.FileName; // get name of file
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open), new UTF8Encoding())) // do anything you want, e.g. read it
        {
            // reader will be having all data
        }
    }
}
```